# Email regex pattern in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want regex to validate Email Address, which rejects the email addresses like `123@gmail.com` or `abc-kumar@gmail.com` or `Raman kumar@gmail.com`.

It allow the emails which are containing at least one character or 'combination of number & characters' for example:- 
`kumar123@gmail.com`, `abc564@xyz.com`, `kumar@outlook.com`

Comment: Write specific conditions for regex in your question.

Comment: so what kind of email format should be allowed? Please mention that in question. that will be helpful for specific question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation function I use:

```
function isEmail(email) {
    var emailFormat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
    if (email !== '' && email.match(emailFormat)) { return true; }
    
    return false;
}
```

However, in your specific case, to further filter out cases like '123@gmail.com' and 'abc-kumar@gmail.com', the regexp shall be modified a bit into:

```
var emailFormat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
```

or, more elegantly:

```
var emailFormat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+(?<!^[0-9]*)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
```

Reference: [Regex: only alphanumeric but not if this is pure numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773297/regex-only-alphanumeric-but-not-if-this-is-pure-numeric)

Comment: Thanks brother, it's working

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Comment: Line 3 ff. can imho be simplified to `return (!! email.match(emailFormat)` (will be false on empty string, will return `true` resp. `false` on match/non-match)